# How to make a regular expression that matches two substrings that are separated by other strings

Tags: regex

I've this string `https://mywebsite.com/myPets/localPets#name=testz0` and I would like to check whether in this string there is the pattern `name` and there is `zx` where `x` is any non-negative integer.

So `https://mywebsite.com/myPets/localPets#name=testz0` should return yes

`https://mywebsite.com/myPets/localPets#name=test` should return no due to `zx` part is missing.

`https://mywebsite.com/myPets/localPets#name=testz999` should return yes

`https://mywebsite.com/myPets/localPets#=testz0` should return no due to `name missing`

I'm not able to figure out on my own, any advice?

EDIT: I had this in mind `(name)&(z(\d+))` but it is returning 0 matches, demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/1UNOfu/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(?:[^#]*#{1})(name=.*?z\d*)$` should do it.

Demo 1: https://regex101.com/r/rnaul7/1

Demo 2:

```js
const regex = /^(?:[^#]*#{1})(name=.*?z\d*)$/;
const url = 'https://mywebsite.com/myPets/localPets#name=testz0'
const result = regex.exec(url);

console.log(result[1])
```

Explanation:

1. `^` the start, matches the position before the first character in the string
2. `(?:[^#]*#{1})`

   - `?:` Non-capturing group.
   - `[^#]*` match any character that is basically not a `#`.
   - `#{1}` `#` should only occur once in a URL, since a URL path is terminated either by a `?` or `#`. (see the 5th test string in demo 1)
3. `(name=.*?z\d*)`: .

   - `()` Capturing group
   - `name=` self-explanatory
   - `.*?` non-greedy expression, match any character
   - `z` self-explanatory
   - `\d*` match digits only
4. `$` the end, matches right after the last character in the string

Comment: Oh boy, this seems to work but looks terrifying. Mind explaining it a bit?

Comment: @Doesitmatter Sure. I updated my answer. I hope it's clear.

Comment: what about if I don't want  the matching group to contain the 'test' string, so the result of the match would be name=z0 or name=z999;is it possible in one regex?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `location.hash` to extract the `#` part of the website. Then split on `=`, check the `key=value`. If `key != name`, you'll have the `name missing` case.

Then check for `/testz\d+/` to deal with the other three cases.

Comment: I actually had a very similar solution to what you suggest for the other three cases but not sure how to capture the first ones. Check my edit pls

Comment: Why would you want to capture the literal `name`?
Anyway, `/(name)=testz(\d+)/` does the trick?
You'll need another check for the positivity resp. non-negativity of the `x` part of `zx`.

Comment: `test` is not always in there so that is why i need to skip it but the z part could be in there but also could not be and the same for name so i wanna check for the presence of both of them and for the correctness of the zx part if it exist